# Why doesn't this route work if I change its order in RouteConfig?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I access this route `http://localhost:60015/myroute`, it does not work if the order of the route like so:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "myroute",
           "myroute/{name}",
           new { controller = "myroute", action = "search", name = "" }
         );

    }
```

It works if I reverse the order. What does that mean? How does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is because The order of the routes that you add to the route table is important. Your new custom route should be added before the existing Default route. If you reversed the order, then the Default route always will get called instead of the custom route.

Comment: But why the default route will get called and I enter this route, `http://localhost:60015/myroute`, which has nothing mataches the default route? How does that work technically?